# Why cant i find a <p> within a <span> tag in this html example?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, scrapy

I have a value I need to grab out of a div tag. Within the div there is a `<p>`, `<span>` and `<input>`. When I write out the results of the `find_all` for the main `<div>` I can see everything I want to get. But when I look for all the `<span>` tags within that main div, the one I need doesn't exist/return in the results.

This is what is actually on the page source

```
<div class="video-details">
   <p>Web ID: <span itemprop="sku">15COLU2BRNRSTVXXXCAC</span></p>
   <span id="SkuDisplay">
      <p> SKU: 12139884</p>
   </span> 
<input type="hidden" id="selectedSku" value="660852" autocomplete="off">
</div>
```

This is what I have right now that will return everything in(spanSKUitems) above except for the `<p> SKU </p>` line

```
for spanSKUitems in soup.find_all('div',class_="video-details"):
    for spanSKUitem in spanSKUitems.find_all('span'):
        strspanSKUitem = str(spanSKUitem.get_text())
        if 'SKU:' in strspanSKUitem:
            bidx = strspanSKUitem.index(':')+1
            lidx = len(strspanSKUitem)
            dets['sku']=strspanSKUitem[bidx:lidx].lstrip()
```

This is what is contained in the `spanSKUitems`:

```
<div class="video-details">
<p>Web ID: <span itemprop="sku">15COLU2BRNRSTVXXXCAC</span></p>
<span id="SkuDisplay"></span> 
<input id="selectedSku" type="hidden" value=""/></div>
```

What am I missing or doing wrong?
What do I need to get is this tag `<p> SKU: 12139884</p>`?

Comment: What is the current output when you run this code?

Comment: the last part in my post is what is returned... notice tht the skudisplay is blank.. how can it be blank if its there when you view the page source..

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem: I get `"12139884"` for `dets['sku']`. Is this your exact code?

Comment: everything above is exactly as it is on the page and as i am executing it withing the spider. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works based on your additional html provided. The data is in a string of a span tag with a different id. You can load with json and then extract:

```
import json
data = soup.select_one('#skuDescriptivattribute').text
data = json.loads(data)
print(data['descriptive'][0]['partNumber'])
```

Comment: if i add the print the last 2 lines in your example i receive this error NotImplementedError: Only the following pseudo-classes are implemented: nth-of-type.

Comment: there will or should only be 1 tag with that name "video-details" and as for the sku in that particular format and structure, only 1 as well, BUT within the entire page there are other tags and elements on the page that contain the word Sku, but not like the above example..

Comment: this is using bs4 4.7.1

Comment: I have beautifulsoup4-4.6.0

Comment: if you have the option to upgrade I would as 4.7.1 offers so much more flexibility

Comment: This version print(soup.select_one('#SkuDisplay').text.strip())   doesn't require 4.7.1

Comment: i cant upgrade without a whole bunch of approvals and such... and when i run that line alone, i get nothing.. there has to be something im missing..    here is the actual site link to the page where the data resides       https://www.dickssportinggoods.com/p/coleman-2-burner-propane-camp-stove-15colu2brnrstvxxxcac/15colu2brnrstvxxxcac?

Comment: I can't visit that page (GDPR). Can you pastebin.com the print out of soup?

Comment: How do you paste all that?

Comment: if you print soup and copy it (or write to file and copy from there if easier) then paste in https://pastebin.com/  and select create > new > paste then share link

Comment: that works, but why? I see that you are getting it from the javascript portion, i was trying that earlier as well, but wasnt having any luck..  is it because that value is dynamic?

Comment: Where you using that id? Also, it is coming from a span tag.